# Docker client attaching to docker daemon

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and I try to find out how and if it's possible to attach the docker client to a host with a docker engine. My docker-engine runs on centOS in a virtual machine. Now I try to install a docker-client on my laptop to connect the client to the VM with the docker engine. Is there any possibility to do that?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Looks like your POST isn't really related to programming. Try posting this Q on ServerFault instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use DOCKER_HOST environment variable and set it to the remote machine IP and port.

something like this -

```
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
```

type docker-machine env to see if the environment is set correctly

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is possible. you need to set the environment variables in the docker client to specify which host to connect to:

`DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=<path to certificates>`

(2375 is the insecure port and 2376 uses TLS). in order to use the secure connection, you need to have the certificates on the client machine.

this is assuming the docker daemon on the host machine has been set up to listen on a tcp socket (instead of named pipe)